# What eigenvalue corresponds to this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help with the following question. Thank You!

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, try http://math.stackexchange.com/, and you need to show your effort.

Comment: Fair warning, although I don't personally mind, posting what appears to be a homework problem on SO is basically asking for downvotes. Second of all, this looks like a problem better suited for Math.SE, so you may want to post it there instead.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I do apologize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be flawed. I have made the following calculations:

```
1, 0, 0.09, 0
0, 1, 0, 0.09
-1.8, 0.9, 1, 0
0.9, -1.8, 0, 1

-i
i
sqrt(30)
-sqrt(30)

-i + 0.09 * sqrt(30) = (a + b * i) * (-i) = b - a * i
i - 0.09 * sqrt(30) = (a + b * i) * i = -b + a * i
-1.8 * i + 0.9 * i + sqrt(30) = -0.9 * i + sqrt(30) = (a + b * i) * sqrt(30)
1.8 * i - 0.9 * i - sqrt(30) = 0.9 * i - sqrt(30) = (a + b * i) * (-sqrt(30))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

i - 0.09 * sqrt(30) = a * i - b
0.9 * i - sqrt(30) = -sqrt(30) * a - sqrt(30) * b * i

a = 1
b = 0.09 * sqrt(30)

Check results:
b - a * i = 0.09 * sqrt(30) - i
(a + b * i) * sqrt(30) = sqrt(30) + i * (0.09 * sqrt(30)) * sqrt(30) = sqrt(30) + i * 30 * 0.09 = sqrt(30) + i * 2.7
```

When I check the results, a and b are calculated for the first row of the eigenvector and naturally, they are correct for the second row as well, as there is only a sign difference. But the imaginary part of the third and fourth row do not comply to the formulas defining the collaboration between eigenvectors and eigenvalues. If I have made  a mistake, please, point out, but I have checked my calculations four times.

Comment: Your calculations seem to be correct! There was an error in the system that generated the vector. So perhaps that contributed to your frustrations. Thank you for your time!!